# How can I improve my resume profile section to get my intent across?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, job-search, company-culture

I'm a relatively-junior dev being out of university for 2.5 years. I've been working at a start-up game dev company and it's not working out. I just don't fit in at all. You can see my other posts to read about this.

Here is what I'm looking for:

- highly-collaborative environment where you actually want and need to
  bounce ideas off of others
- supportive senior devs who actually want
  to give you the time of day and mentor you when they have time
- object-oriented programming
- nice, friendly and non-judgmental coworkers
- i have a degree in science so I like to have a slow, methodical, and abstract approach to projects
- respect for each other as a colleague and wanting to invest in each others skills and experiences

Here is what I have so far:

> Objective
>
> Software Developer with 3 years of experience looking to be part of a
>   highly-collaborative and closely-knit team where knowledge-sharing and
>   mentorship are appreciated. Takes pride in a methodical and
>   concept-driven approach to programming.

edit:

I've decided that a summary/profile is better then? I want to get out of the gaming industry and move into something more low-key.

Is this effective? How would you change it? Do I need to explain why I want to leave gaming? I have a Skills Summary just below this 'profile' section.

> Software Developer with 3 years of experience programming games in XYZ for mobile devices. Looking to be part of a highly-collaborative
>   and closely-knit team where knowledge-sharing and mentorship are
>   appreciated. Hands-on experience with a variety of technologies.
>   Interested in exploring opportunities outside the gaming industry.

Comment: Pleased to know that you have finally decided to move on from fighting out those guys. :) That aside, "objective" is just wasted real estate on a resume. Hate to put it this way, but nobody cares what your objective is, they are looking for someone to do their work. I would much rather put a "Skills Summary" or something in place of the objective.

Comment: I want to see what you have accomplished and what skill set you have. I am never going to hire you besed on a an objective, it may well prevent you from being hired at a lot of places that don't feel as if they fit. It that is what you are trying to accomplish, then go fir it but be aware that your job search will take much longer. What will serve you better is to make sure you interview them about their work culture rather than being passive about what you are looking for in the interview.

Comment: Isn't a laundry-list of skills a bad thing and hard to read? Is it better just to list the tools used in the experience section? Instead of an objective isn't a profile better?

Comment: @Kerry You can choose the specific details based on what the hiring managers in your location generally prefer. My point here is your resume is more likely to be shortlisted with "3 years experience in game development using C++" rather than "I want to be the most kickass employee in the most awesome organization known to humanity".

Comment: I also made the mistake of writing an Objective section, filling it with nonsense, and ended up getting a grand total of 2 interview calls over 3 months (from what turned out to be companies desperately looking for a team lead). After I replaced it with Skills Summary, I started getting "flooded" with interview calls, often 3 or more every week. I was even forced to decline some calls because there were too many interviews scheduled on the same day.

Comment: I don't think it's worthwhile to write out what you're looking for at all unless it's an extremely objective requirement, for example, you are unwilling to relocate out of state.  Your requirements are much more subjective, and thus not at all helpful for weeding out companies.  How can they tell if they fit your definition of "highly collaborative," for example.  It's up to you during the interview process to determine that, by asking questions.

Answer (score 6):

I never include an Objectives section on my resume.

Your Objectives section is very nicely written and it very clearly sums up what you are looking for. Any interview will inevitably focus on your Objectives section and inevitably, what you are not getting from your current employer. At which point, the skeletons tumble out of your closet and every issue that you have with your current employer gets aired. And the more vehemence you put into describing your experience with your current employer, the less likely a prospective employer will want to hire you.

Prospective employers don't hire you because they like you, they hire you because they need you. Your needs to them are somewhere between irrelevant and a pain in the butt. Whatever you do, don't let them perceive that your needs are a pain in their butt.

Answer (score 2):

What you have written seems perfectly fine.

I think the problem you are going to have is that the workplace you are looking for doesn't exist. If you do find it though, can you ask if they have a position for me?